# How to INSERT INTO table column with string/variable

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, powershell, printers

This is the data I have pulled from powershell and inserted it into a #temptable:

```
Name                   : SULESRKMA
Location               : Leisure Services - Technology Services
Shared                 : False
ShareName              : 
JobCountSinceLastReset : 0
PrinterState           : 131072
Status                 : Degraded
Network                : False
```

I'm while looping through the data and have stripped the values from the identifiers.  I'd like to use these identifiers to insert the values into a table  with identical Column names to the identifiers.  So for example, I have a variable called @identifier = "Name" and a temp table #printers with a column name of Name.  I'd like to do something like:

```
SELECT --select statement
INSERT INTO #printers(@identifier)
```

But This doesn't seem to work, unsurprisingly.  Is there a way to accomplish this?  (The @identifier variable will be changing to the other identifiers in the data throughout the course of the while loop.)

Any alternate suggestions that don't even involve using this sort of method are welcome.  My ultimate goal is just to get this data as a row into a table.

(I'm currently using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio if that matters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's unlikely you need to loop over anything in this situation. Think set based operations when you think about SQL.

```
INSERT INTO #temptable (Column1Name, Column2Name, Column3Name)
VALUES (@identifer, @anotherIdentifier, @someOtherIdentifier)
--optional clauses
WHERE Column1Name = 'some value' OR Column1Name = @someIdentifier
```

Or you can `SELECT INTO`

```
SELECT
@identifier,
@anotherIdentifer,
@someOtherIdentifier
INTO #temptable
```

It's important that you have a value in your `SELECT INTO` for each column in the table which you are trying to add the data to. So, for example, if there were 4 columns in `#temptable` and you only had 3 values to insert (columns 1, 2 , and 3) then you'd need to `NULL` column 4 or set it statically.

```
SELECT
@identifier,
@anotherIdentifer,
@someOtherIdentifier,
NULL
INTO #temptable
--or
    SELECT
@identifier,
@anotherIdentifer,
@someOtherIdentifier,
'static value'
INTO #temptable
```

**EDIT**

If you want to use a varible to speciy the column that you want to insert into, you have to use dynamic sql. Here is an example:

```
if object_id ('tempdb..#tempTable') is not null drop table #tempTable
create table #tempTable (Column1Name int, Column2Name int, Column3Name int)

declare @columnName varchar(64) = 'Column1Name'
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = 
'insert into #tempTable (' + @columnName + ')
select 1'

exec(@sql)

select * from #tempTable
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't want to specify Column1Name, Column2Name, etc.  I want some way of saying "I want to put '@value' into a column specified by '@identifier'"  I don't want to place '@identifier' into the table, I want to specify the column with it.  Does that make sense?

Comment: The reason for this trouble is because I don't want to have to define 10 variables or columns to be placing data in.  I feel like it makes the query less reusable.  This is why I'm while looping through the identifiers (such as 'Name', 'Location', 'Shared', etc. (I'll be reusing this code in an instance where there will be up to 25 different identifiers).

Comment: ah it does @SaniT404 i edtied it above

Comment: I understand @SaniT404, you can use your loop for the variable assignment, that is assigning the correct column name to `@columnName` or what ever you use in your cursor.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you, this looks to be exactly what I was looking for.  I'm actually using something really similar to run the powershell query to retrieve the data.  I'll probably be marking this as the answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: @SaniT404 No worries at all, glad i could help :)

Comment: @SaniT404 something to remember, if @value is going to be an `INT` or `DECIMAL` or something that a math function can be used on, you'll have to convert it in order to `concat` it into the dynamic SQL. Let me know if i need to update the answer to address this.

Comment: Tip: When using dynamic SQL, always prepare for a visit from [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Yup, definitly got to sanitize input @HABO